# TensorFlow network not training?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I had a really weird time with TensorFlow the last days and can not think of what's going wrong atm.

I have built this network: [link](http://pastebin.com/GZaX4aYN). It is a copy of TensorFlow's MNIST example.

Basically, what I did, is altering the network from taking 28x28x1 images (MNIST greyscale) to 600x800x1 images (some images I took on my own, webcam with a relatively clean background and one object at different locations).

What I wanted to do is playing around with such a CNN and have it output the x-location of the object in the image. So one single output neuron.

However, no matter what I tried, the network is always outputting 1.0. Even (when you look at my testing section at the end of the code) when I feed all ones, all zeros or all random numbers into the network.

Of course, since I have only 21 labeled training and 7 labeled test pictures I expected the performance to be really bad (since 800x600 pixel images are huge for neural networks and locating an object isn't easy).

...but I have no idea at all why the network always outputs 1.0 even if it is fed with nonsense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your source code, it appears that your final fully connected layer before the softmax (L.104 in [the code you shared](http://pastebin.com/GZaX4aYN)) reduces each example down to a **single output class** before computing the softmax. Since there is only one class for each example, the result of the [`tf.nn.softmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax) op (`y_conv`) will be a batch_size x 1 matrix containing 1.0 in every element, and the [`tf.argmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#argmax) of that will  containing 0 for every element, since there is only one value. Similarly, applying `tf.argmax()` to y_train (which is a batch_size x 1 matrix) will yield 0 for every element, so the "accuracy" will be 100%.

To fix this, you should probably (i) increase the number of output units from the final fully connected layer to be the number of classes, and (ii) encode each row `y_train` as a one-hot vector representing the true class of each example.

Comment: Ok, I altered y_train and the output layer to be 800 dimensional and one-hot style. So if real x coordinate was e.g. 300, than y_train[300] = 1.0 and all other entries are 0.0. Unfortunately the network refuses to train: directly in the first epoch it crashes with *Tensor had NaN values*. Any ideas?

Comment: Almost certainly this line: `cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_train * tf.log(y_conv))` is computing log(0), which is NaN. Instead of using `tf.nn.softmax()` and manually computing the cross-entropy, try using [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), which is more robust to these issues.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this was the error. It is training now with different training rates for the optimizer :)

Comment: HI.. I have a similar issue But i have already used the soflmax with logits.
It looks like graph is off somewhere.[Could you have a look at my  Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312967/tensorflow-cnn-model-not-training-constant-loss-and-accuracy).@ascenator