# Tensorflow CNN model not training? Constant loss and accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have built a model using [this](https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks/blob/master/tensorflow/benchmark_alexnet.py) as a base.

And the train portion from [this code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/alexnet.py).

This model does not train and always gives the cost/loss output for every iteration.

I dont think it learns anything.

I have checked for the usual stuff like shuffled inputs.
Making sure that each batch is new.

Any idea why ?

This is my [code.](http://pastebin.com/Z4gA5AEG)

## Output

```
Iter 1280, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.03125
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
Iter 2560, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
Iter 3840, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Testing Accuracy: 0.015625
Iter 5120, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Testing Accuracy: 0.078125
Iter 6400, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.03125
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
Iter 7680, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.03125
Testing Accuracy: 0.015625
Iter 8960, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
Iter 10240, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Testing Accuracy: 0.015625
Iter 11520, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
Iter 12800, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.01562
Testing Accuracy: 0.03125
Iter 14080, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.01562
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
Iter 15360, Minibatch Loss= 4.615120, Training Accuracy= 0.01562
Testing Accuracy: 0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you started from is just a benchmark of the forward and backward pass and isn't designed to do training. You should start from an example that actually trains a model instead and ignore the benchmark code.

You might have an easier time starting from a completely working training example program instead of trying to combine two pieces.